# c++ Running a concurrent for loop, even possible?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Given this for loop:

```
std::vector<std::string> V={"element1","element2","element3"};

for(int i=V.size(); i--;)
{
 std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}
```

Is it possible to run each loop of the for loop concurrently? So each std::cout occurs at once?

I have a vector of function pointers that i need to loop through and execute all at the same time, **NOT** one after the other.

Note: std::thread, std::async aren't help full in this case, as I don't know the size of the vector, and therefor have to create a thread each loop and run it.. This doesn't result in concurrency.

Comment: You can also check here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism

Comment: You should further clarify how you want your output to std::cout to look. Do you need a specific order of the outputs?

Comment: in short not possible , even though you use threading they, all not gonna execute at same time

Comment: I mean... you could create the threads and have them all wait on a condition variable, and then after they're created you signal the condition, but @PavneetSingh is right, they'll never run "at the same time" but rather have interleaved execution. It's probably good enough though. Perhaps some more clarification about the desired outcome would help.

Comment: Threads can certainly execute concurrently...

Comment: Certainly there exists something like a countdown-latch: start and run N threads, that all first block on the countdown latch of N until the N'th reaches the latch. - cout parallel though?

Comment: `tbb::parallel_for` might be what you're looking for (https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/parallel_for.html).

Comment: Can you clarify "execute all at the same time"?  If you have multiple cores or processors, you can indeed have multiple things happening concurrently, although shared resources like the memory bus will induce some sequentiality.

Comment: You can divide the vector up into sections - one for each thread you want to allocate for this task and give each thread that portion of  the vector to work on.

Answer (score 1):

It is a work for OpenMP:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < V.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}
```

This uses a fixed count of threads (usually it is a count of CPU threads). If `V.size()` is more than it, not all tasks will be called simultaneously. They will wait for available thread.

If you cannot use OpenMP, third-party libraries and frameworks can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If by executables you mean separate applications you want to launch, then you don't need to utilize threads. You just launch the executables one by one in one thread without waiting for their completion. You can put their PID's in-to a vector. And then in separate loop you wait until these processes finish, again one by one.

But if this is the only thing that you need to do in the program then you'd better consider writing it in bash.

Comment: Then std::thread is your friend. Wrap every function you want to execute in-to a std::thread, put them in-to a vector and then wait for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can run these executables in parallel. This has nothing really to do with running a for loop in parallel. It is more a feature of your operating system.

For Linux look up how to run processes with `fork()`/`exec()`/`system()`.

For Windows look up how to run processes with `CreatrProcess()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to run each loop of the for loop concurrently?

Yes. The C++ standard library provides low level tools to implement concurrency. Simply start a new thread in each iteration - and don't join until all threads have started.

> Note: std::thread, std::async aren't help full in this case, as I don't know the size of the vector, and therefor have to create a thread each loop and run it.. This doesn't result in concurrency.

You are mistaken. `std::thread` (and possibly `std::asnyc` as well) are useful and can be used to implement concurrency in this case. Creating the threads in each loop doesn't prevent concurrency. A trivial demonstration using function pointers, since that's what you are really intending to use:

```
std::vector<void(*)()> function_pointers = get_the_stuff();
for(auto f : function_pointers) {
    std::thread t(f);
    t.detach();
}
```

Another, marginally more complex, approach would be to create a vector of threads. That allows you to wait until all have executed by joining.

--

`std::thread` and friends are low level tools for concurrency and it may be worth creating an abstraction over them - or use an existing abstraction provided by a third party.

Also, I urge you to reconsider. You say that you don't know the size of the vector. Surely, your hardware provider doesn't know the vector either. How would they know to supply you with enough cpu cores to execute all threads in parallel? A better approach is to use a constant pool of threads depending on the number of available cores to avoid the overhead of extra threads.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by using threads not resulting in concurrency? Do you want all threads to instantly create threads over a vector of function pointers, instead of having a for loop that iterates over `V` and creates threads? I don't think that's possible, and it's very likely the other answers end up doing the exact same thing, at different levels of abstraction.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

typedef void (*func)();

std::atomic<int> atom;

void f1() { ++atom; }
void f2() { atom += 5; }
void f3() { atom -= 3; }

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<func> func_vec = { &f1, &f2, &f3 };
    vector<thread> thread_vec;

    for (func& f : func_vec)
        thread_vec.emplace_back(std::thread(f));

    for (thread& t : thread_vec)
        t.join();

    std::cout << "Atomic : " << atom;
}
```

There likely is a better way to fill up `thread_vec` (i.e. iterating over both func_vec and thread_vec with `thread_vec`'s size set to `func_vec`'s), but that's fine for an example. If you don't need the threads to end properly until the end of the main thread's execution, you may drop out the `thread_vec` entirely and create a thread you're immediately detaching as this other answer [demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39593684/6261331).